# ServiceWorkerRegistration#installing values on repeat visit?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((reg)=>{
            console.log(reg.installing, " installing");  
            console.log(reg.waiting, " waiting"); 
            console.log(reg.active, " active") 
            reg.addEventListener('updatefound', function(){
                console.log("update found", reg.installing); 
            })
})
```

**Case A)** let's say user goes to the first time ever to my website. `reg.installing` prints `worker` object. `reg.waiting` and `reg.active` undefined which is understandable. `updatefound` runs immediatelly and `reg.installing` is the same worker as the above . All is good.

**Case B)** I updated SW code and deployed it. when refreshing the page, `reg.installing` prints undefined. **Question 1)** Why undefined? when refreshed, new service worker appears, but `reg.installing` is undefined.  in case A, when browser went to the website, a new service worker had to be installed, so `reg.installing` wasn't undefined.

My assumption: in my opinion, in Case B) `then promise block` happened faster than the browser actually compared old one with a new one, so when that happened, browser didn't have `reg.installing` at all.  and in Case A, because it was first time, browser didn't have to compare anything and it was faster enough to put `worker` in `reg.installing`.

**Question 2)** does my assumption make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend reading "[The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)" for an in-depth background.

The service worker lifecycle happens independently from any activities on client pages, and by the time your code executes, yes, it's entirely possible that the updated service worker has moved from the `installing` state to the `waiting` state (or `active`, if you've called `skipWaiting()`).

So yes, your assumption sounds like it would basically be correct.